# Paging in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hello guys help me with this problem.
I have table name comments in SQL.
I applied paging in SQL procedure.

- step-1:Firstly i fetch page 1 with 5 records
- step-2:Now Created new comment.
- step-3:Fetch page 2 with 5 records.
- step-4:Got 5 rows that is fine but i got one record again which was in page 1 also

This happens because every time i create new comment the last comments will be shifted by one and each time i am facing this kind problem.

Ex.

```
create proc getComments(@PageNumber tinyint,@PerPage INT,@TotalRecords INT OUTPUT)
AS
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(RowNumber SMALLINT,Id int,CommentText nvarchar(max),CommentedBy nvarchar(256),CommentTime datetime

INSERT INTO #TempTable
    (RowNumber,Id ,CommentText ,CommentedBy ,CommentTime )
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CommentTime desc),Id,CommentText,CommentedBy ,CommentTime from comments
 SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(Id) FROM #TempTable

 SELECT * FROM #TempTable
    where RowNumber > (@PageNumber - 1) * @PerPage
    AND RowNumber <= @PageNumber * @PerPage 

GO
```

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: MS-SQL-2012 but i guess this issue is not related to version

Comment: `"the last comments will be shifted by one"` - How are you ordering the records?  If you're selecting by the most recent at the top and a new record is added then, yes, it's going to shift the rest of the records.  By design.  What change to that logic do you propose?

Comment: yes i m selecting recent at the top right now.

Comment: ok then any suggestion to get right data with change of paging also

Comment: ok let me tell u again ,

Comment: i have page 1 data , now i create two new comments , now i wanna call page 2 with different data not duplicate one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are getting exactly what you are asking for in SQL.  When you run the stored proc the next time with the additional row inserted, that row is being factored into the results of the query.

The only way to prevent new data from affecting your paging results is to remove the new data or begin paging again from the last record of the original page.

This assumes your `Id` column is an incrementing value.

```
CREATE PROC getComments(
    @PageNumber tinyint, @PerPage INT,
    @LastIdFromPreviousPage INT, @TotalRecords INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    (RowNumber SMALLINT, Id INT, CommentText NVARCHAR(MAX),
        CommentedBy NVARCHAR(256),CommentTime DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO #TempTable
        (RowNumber, Id, CommentText, CommentedBy, CommentTime)
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CommentTime desc),
        Id, CommentText, CommentedBy, CommentTime
    FROM comments

    SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(Id) FROM #TempTable

    SELECT *
    FROM #TempTable
    WHERE (@LastIdFromPreviousPage IS NULL
        AND RowNumber > (@PageNumber - 1) * @PerPage
        AND RowNumber <= @PageNumber * @PerPage)
        OR (Id < @LastIdFromPreviousPage
            AND Id >= @LastIdFromPreviousPage - @PerPage)
END
GO
```

You could also change @LastIdFromPreviousPage to be a DATETIME of the first time you began paging and filter your results to begin paging after that date when you return the data.

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'END'.

Comment: [AND @PerPage + @LastIdFromPreviousPage]      i guess error in this there no boolen output from this

Comment: i tries to run procedure without  this line [AND @PerPage + @LastIdFromPreviousPage]  and worked, and now it gives me new records which was added after the LastId.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server 2012 introduced the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses to allow an easy syntax for paging query results. I would suggest using it.

Also, I would suggest reading Aaron Bertrand's [Pagination with OFFSET / FETCH : A better way](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) article, especially of you encounter performance issues with pagination.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getComments (
    @PageNumber tinyint,
    @PerPage INT,
    @TotalRecords INT OUTPUT
)
AS

SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(Id) FROM comments;

SELECT Id, CommentText, CommentedBy ,CommentTime 
FROM comments
ORDER BY CommentTime desc
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @PerPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PerPage ROWS ONLY;

GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, let me apply this and test

Comment: Still same problem in this.